# Checking for subset of a list in another list of lists in R

Tags: r, list, subset

I have a list:
`l1 = list(1, 3, 5)`

I have another list:
`l2 = list(list(1, 3), list(2, 6), list(3, 5), list(1, 5))`

I want to check if each 2-item subset of l1 (i.e. `list(1, 3)`, `list(1, 5)` and `list(3, 5)`) exist in l2 or not.

In this case I just wants a direct answer as `TRUE`.
How can I do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First find all possible combinations of `l1`, returned as a list of lists.

```
cmb <- combn(l1, 2, simplify = FALSE)
```

Scrubbing my original answer, and building on @alexis_laz's comment, you want `%in%`.

```
l2 <- list(list(1, 3), list(2, 6), list(3, 5), list(1, 5))
cmb %in% l2
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
all(cmb %in% l2)
# [1] TRUE
```

But when we have the new `l2` OP mentions in the comments (I'll call it `l3`), we get

```
l3 <- list(list(1, 3), list(2, 6), list(3, 5), list(1, 6)) 
cmb %in% l3
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
all(cmb %in% l3)
# [1] FALSE
```

Comment: I think `any` should be `all`, isn't it? Secondly, should `list(1, 3)` and `list(3, 1)` be considered the same?

Comment: Having `cmb`, an alternative seems to be `all(cmb %in% l2)`